# multiple null arguments to a method taking varargs causes null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I run into a null pointer exception when i run this:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long a = getValue();
        Long b = getValue();
        Long c = sum(a, b);
    }

    private static Long getValue() {
        return null;
    }

    private static long sum(final long... values) {
        long sum = 0L;
        for(final long value: values) {
            sum += value;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

The stack trace:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mypackage.test.main(test.java:10)

Why is the null pointer being thrown at this line:
    Long c = sum(a, b);

Comment: What do you do with `values` inside the method?

Comment: yes. Long, not long.

Comment: inside values, i do something like this:
Long sum = 0L;
for(Long value : values) {
sum += value;
}

Comment: Especially when you are already working with a small scale example: please provide code that compiles; and ideally runs and shows the unexpected behavior. If that is not possible, add the exception stack trace to your question. As it is right now, your question is pretty much un-answerable. And note: do NEVER provide more information in comments; always update the question!

Comment: Give your `sum()` method definition or the stacktrace.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since your method `sum(final long... values)` uses primitives, you can't simply put Long values inside the method when they are `null`.

For valid Long-values this happens:

```
Long value1 = 1L;
Long value2 = 2.0L;
sum(value1, value2);    // value1 and value2 will be unboxed from Long to long, 
                        // and then used in the method
```

For non-valid Long-values this happens:

```
Long value1 = null;
Long value2 = null;
sum(value1, value2);     // value1 and value2 will be unboxed from Long to long,
                             // giving an error because they are null, which is not a valid primitive value
```

Try something like this instead:

```
Long value1 = null;
Long value2 = null;
if(value1 == null || value2 == null) return; // or something else like continue, logging, etc.
sum(value1, value2);
```

Or, if you still want to sum the values and count `null` as `0`, use this:

```
Long value1 = null;
Long value2 = null;
value1 = value1 != null ? value1 : 0L;
value2 = value2 != null ? value2 : 0L;
sum(value1, value2);
```

Or, change the parameter-type of the `sum` method to `Long` instead of `long` and do one of these two checks inside the method.

Comment: Thanks for that Kevin. I liked the last idea. Though i don't think there is a null coalescing operator in java. I will use the alternative you mentioned in the commented part.

Comment: @anilgopalakrishna Ah, you're indeed right; edited. I'm so used to C# lately that I forgot Java doesn't have a `??`-operator.. Btw, it was the single last idea. The last idea was changing the `sum(long...)` to `sum(Long...)` and do the check inside the method itself. See @Eran's answer to see how this can be implemented in code.

Comment: Actually the code i posted was a simpler form of a bigger piece of code i am working on. Since it is an enterprise software, i can't copy paste the actual code. Your solution was the best bet in my circumstance. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @anilgopalakrishna I thought that was the case, since most people don't use `...` parameters in their own code in most occasions. Glad I could help.